# Add/Edit JSON data iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, ios7

I am using the below code to fetch JSON data from my local drive.
 It works quite well

**Now I want to add my JSON data to the Same URL**

I don't want create and replace the previous json file

Is it possible??

Is there any easy way to do it??

```
NSURL *fileUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"localDriveURL"];
//NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileUrl];
NSError* error;

NSArray* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data //1
                                                     options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                       error:&error];

NSArray *json2=[json valueForKey:@"locations"];

for (int i=0; i<json2.count; i++) {

}
```

Comment: You mean append data locally and upload to DropBox? Did you check the DropBox API docs?

Comment: @Wain Thanks for the Reply  I've edited my question How can edit or append JSON data to local file I'don't want to replace it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the file is part of the app bundle, you can't change anything about it.

Generally speaking you do want to replace the existing file.

While you could use `NSFileHandle` to write additional data into the file it is relatively complex and relatively likely to corrupt the JSON (when you make an indexing mistake or something like that).

Your best option is to read the data in mutable (as you are), then modify and use `NSJSONSerialization` to convert back to data again, then save that data to disk (replacing the original).

Your current code should really be:

```
NSMutableArray* json = [...
```

because of the mutable container option you're using.

You can then add some new items to the array:

```
[json addObject:@"Stuff"];
[json insertObject:@"Other Stuff" atIndex:0];
```

Then re-save:

```
data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:json options:nil error:&error];
[data writeToURL:fileUrl atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Sorry I'm a newbie. Is there any tutorial or sample project??

Answer (score 0):

In my code I append JSON to an open file with the following (well I actually made a macro)

I do it both with the serialization and just normal text I type to format it a little better:

For normal text I made a macro to append:

```
#define jsonAppend(X) [outStream write:[[@X dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] bytes] maxLength:[@X lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]
```

-> you would have to open an output stream to your file and queue it up to the end I would suppose but in my code I just call

```
jsonAppend("WhatEverIwAntToAppend");
```

And as far as appending to an existing JSON structure:

```
[NSJsonSerialization writeJSONObject:My-Dictionary-Object toStream:outStream options:1 error:&error]
```

Again as long as you have a file handle it should be easy.

With regards to how to open a stream in append mode check: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsoutputstream_class/reference/reference.html

Comment: While this solution will work well for streaming out to a file, it is better suited to full file creation at the same time (due to JSON structure). Editing an existing file won't work so well (need to delete sections before starting to append). Do you use this for editing or only new files?