# Is it possible to update the information in a JSON file from ios application?

Tags: json, swift

Sorry if my question is stupid, but I was wondering is it possible to update the information in my JSON file from an ios application. I am currently developing a swift app which uses lots of JSON files and it will be great if I can update the JSON files from another application. By updating I mean changing some pictures and names.

P.S My JSON files are hosted on a server and my application uses URL link to find them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add/Edit JSON data iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21751374/add-edit-json-data-ios)

Answer (score -1):

You can look this library : 
https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON => For read and write json file 
And this for get json with url : 
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

You can directly create a JSON object with response of request like this :

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url).validate().responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .Success:
        if let value = response.result.value {
          let json = JSON(value)
          print("JSON: \(json)")
        }
    case .Failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Just read docs of open source project for more informations.

Comment: The question is not really clear. I understood he was trying to make an application to edit JSON files. Swity json is the best solution to handle json file. But sorry if i don't understood the question.

Comment: You receive json file, store it locally. Then edit it in local with swiftyjson and send it to the server.